# Can one "saferoot" 4.4.2?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-4, 4.4-kitkat

I know that a Samsung 4.3 can be rooted using a method called saferoot. What it does is find a security hole in the OS and performs a "privilege escalation" on the process.

The advantage of this is that it doesn't touch the ROM and has little risk of bricking one's phone.

I assume that they fixed this specific exploit in 4.4.2. I want to know if there is another method like this?

Answer (score -1):

Technically speaking there's no completely safe rooting of any devices, this is because rooting allows complete access to device files. So rooting no there's no really 'safe' way. You can however root your phone and then just be careful with what you install and do on your phone. I honestly don't see much of a reason to root a phone, but if you want to then just be careful. Also there had not been a release of saferoot and probably won't be for awhile due to Android 4.4 KitKat still being a fairly new OS.

Comment: You seem to be answering the question "is it safe to 'root' my phone?" The actual question, though, is there an equivalent to "saferoot" for Android 4.4.

Comment: Safe means safe from the device, not safe from me. I have "root" on my computer and I still didn't format it. The problem with flashing a ROM is that if something goes wrong (wrong device, mistaken options), your device is bricked.